# Post on Facebook Page from a Worklow c#

Tags: c#, facebook

I need to create a workflow activity which allows to post on a specific facebook page. Can I do this with the AppId and the AppSecret only? I found no way to do it without user interaction (user FB Login).

Is there such a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a Page Access Token for that, as you can read in the Facebook docs for feed publishing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Information about Access Tokens and how to create a Page Token can be found here, for example:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Make sure you are familiar with all of them and make sure you understand how and when to use them.